# How to listen to a tcp port using socket io?

Tags: java, socket.io, engine.io, socket.io-java-client

I have an application which is writing on a port(TCP message using spring-integration tcp-outbound-channel on a particular port). I want to write a listener which will listen and validate the message coming on this port.

One of the recommendation is to use socket.io. I tried to do a sample POC, But I am unable to start non http server. How can I start a socket.io based server which will listen to messages sent over TCP( without http).

Comment: Can you share what you have already tried?

Comment: Just an alternate way: I have came across same scenario, I have used plain java.net.ServerSocket (socket programming) to continuously listen and write back to port.Like creating ServerSocket instance for given port, read and  write using input and output streams.

Comment: @Shaq,I tried various thing , In java I couldn't find any example which doesn't include http. So I went node js way. I am not putting sample in question as it is not java. Here is a sample  `var engine = require('engine.io');
var server = engine.listen(1603);

server.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.send('utf 8 string');
  socket.send(Buffer.from([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // binary data
}); 
 `

Comment: [Suseendran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/952507/suseendran-p) I am also thinking about the same , but I thought of getting second opinion before committing on my decision.